# How does sql server derive the `Restore As` value?

Tags: restore, ssms, sql-server-2019

[image]

When I'm restoring a database, it is auto populating the original file name and restore as.

The check box (relocate all files to folder) is to change the destination path.

No matter if this checkbox is selected or not, the restore as default value is the same.

Is the default value for the relocate setting, and the `Restore As` value same as the default data and log file locations configured on the sql server?

Answer (score 0):

The default location for `Restore As` is just the original location for the file, which is stored inside the backup file, as part of the headers for each database file that was backed up.

You can see this using the [`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) command. Look at the `LogicalName` and `PhysicalName` columns. Use the `WITH FILE = number` parameter to specify which file you want.

| LogicalName | PhysicalName | Type | FileGroupName | Size | MaxSize | FileId | CreateLSN | DropLSN | UniqueId | ReadOnlyLSN | ReadWriteLSN | BackupSizeInBytes | SourceBlockSize | FileGroupId | LogGroupGUID | DifferentialBaseLSN | DifferentialBaseGUID | IsReadOnly | IsPresent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AdventureWorks_Data | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf | D | PRIMARY | 202113024 | 3.51844E+13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 50A534B0-156C-42B7-82FE-A57D21A53EEA | 0 | 0 | 177012736 | 512 | 1 | NULL | 0 | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: So the path comes from backup file, and the new database name is amended in the path by this UI?

Comment: Yes I think that's how it works